# How do i get the newly opened page after a form submission using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, web-crawler, puppeteer, headless-browser

I have a website which i want to crawl, where when i submit a form i am opening it into a new page using Command + Click in macOS.

It is working fine and after the submission of the form it is opening in new page, but now the problem arises that how do i get the new page content

```
console.log('before new page')
const [firsPage] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation({
        timeout: 0
    }),
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        document.addEventListener(
            'contextmenu',
            (event) => event.stopPropagation(),
            true
        )
    }),
    await page.keyboard.down('Meta'),
    await page.click('input[type="submit"][name="formsearch"]'),
    await page.keyboard.up('Meta'),
])
console.log('after new page')
console.log('First page is ' + firsPage.url())
console.log('Browser page are ' + (await browser.pages()))
```

Here it outputs

```
before new page
```

Thats it does not go forward.It does not return the newpage as well as does not print

```
console.log('after new page')
console.log('First page is ' + firsPage.url())
console.log('Browser page are ' + (await browser.pages()))
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Same comments as your last post which was deleted: don't use timeout: 0, don't `await` promises you're passing to `Promise.all()`, which defeats the purpose of `Promise.all()`.